# Get week number of a date in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a class that contains other classes

```
export class Sensor {
  public id: string;
  public label: string;
  public measures: Measure[];
  constructor(dbDate){

  }
}

export class Message {
  public id: string;
  public arrivalTimestamp: Date;
  public sensors: Sensor[];
  constructor(dbData: any) {
      this.id= dbData.id;
      this.arrivalTimestamp= dbData.value.timestamp ;
      this.sensors = new Sensor(dbData);
  }
}
```

I actually face problem : `Type 'Sensor' is not assignable to type 'Sensor[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Sensor'.`

`sensors` have a type of `Array of Sensor` but what I'm affecting it in constructor to it is of type `Sensor`.

I have tried to add brakets `new Sensor[](dbData);` but it's not working I get VS Code warning message `An element access expression should take an argument.`

Comment: `this.sensors = new Sensor(dbData);` should be: `this.sensors = [new Sensor(dbData)];`, since it was declared as an array of `Sensor`. So, what is the real problem? getting the week number or **compiling** that code specifically?... Or both? Is the week number of the **year** or of the **month**?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is just having an array of one element, not an element of type "Array of Sensor".

In javascript, you can create an array on the fly just wrapping your variable with square brackets:

```
this.sensors = [new Sensor(dbData)];
```

In this way `this.sensors` will always have one element. Otherwise, you can also initialise the `sensors` variable as empty array:

```
public sensors: Sensor[] = [];
```

then use the push method:

```
this.sensors.push(new Sensor(dbData));
```

this method will add the element to the array

Comment: dbData.sensors  is an array of documents so should i something like : `dbData.sensors.map(elm=> this.sensors.push(elm));` ?

Comment: Yes, but `map` is useless in this context, because it will return an array of numbers. You can use either  `this.sensors = this.sensors.concat(dbData.sensors)` or, the shorter: `this.sensors.push(...dbData.sensors)`